# One Project For Multiple Applications in XCode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am trying to use the approach of having a single project that uses different targets with different plist files.  However, each target has a different set of launch and icon images.  I cant however use a duplicate set of these since adding a duplicate image when the same name gives the error that its already in use.  Is there anyway around this in xcode?

```
To save the file, either provide a different name, or move aside or delete the existing file, and try again.
```

Comment: could you `provide a different name`? I don't use Xcode that much, but this seems like the way to go. Maybe a different folder?

Comment: you can use .sh file and use target name's loop #ifdef.

Comment: You should put those files with same name into different folder. Note that the "folder" in Xcode navigator is actually a "group", you should create folders on file system (probably with Finder) and then add the folder to Xcode.

Comment: Creating the folder structure and adding it to the project worked.  If you made this an answer Id accept.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Xcode 5's assets catalogs. You can define a different assets catalog for each target, and in each assets catalog you can define different launch images. Names are handled by the content generator.

You can mix asset catalogs, so you can have, for example, one shared catalog for shared images, and individual ones for each different target, where you can have distinct icons and launch images.

Comment: Yea but I still have to use different names for the actual images inside the project.

Comment: Not really. When using asset catalogs, you don't have to worry about names.

Comment: I'm trying to load a different image at each target, but it won't. I know I'm running a different target because icon name changes at device, but the loaded image is the same. I have two different Asset Catalogs, one for each target. Both have an image named "logo", but app always displays the same image. Isn't this the right approach?

Comment: PD: ok... that was a CocoaPods bug. See [comment](http://matt.coneybeare.me/using-xcode-asset-catalogs-with-multiple-targets/#comment-1213336157) and [bug](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1546)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I have changed my approach and found the easiest and a simple solution which I ignored before. All you have to do is keep the file names same but keep the files in different folders. And when adding them to project, check the target to which the files belong to and uncheck other targets. [See the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAeBF.png)

Comment: This isnt something realistic for say 100 applications.